# Is there a way to render 3D map tiles?

Tags: openstreetmap, 3d, tiles

I am looking for a way to create map tiles from OSM data but I would like the resulting map tile images rendered at a 45 degree angle. Is there any way this can be done? I have never see such an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a project at https://gitorious.org/osm2blender that imports Openstreetmap map xml data and renders in in 2.5d using the open source 3d suite [Blender](http://www.blender.org/).

An online OpenLayers example of the output can be found at http://www.anzui.de/osm2blender/openlayers/

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You might want to follow [this ticket](http://trac.mapnik.org/ticket/531), which discusses custom map rotations. Those, combined with the [BuildingSymbolizer](http://trac.mapnik.org/wiki/BuildingSymbolizer), might be what you're looking for.

In the meantime, it's certainly possible to use the BuildingSymbolizer within TileMill and elsewhere to achieve a 2.5D effect. Though true 45° tiles, and placing anything on an orthographic map would require a lot of work through the whole stack, especially in the javascript map client.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could rely on osm2x3d project. Demo here: http://web.osm2x3d.net
The main feature is to convert osm xml data to x3d format (3D scene graph).
Also using x3dom js library, it allows to render the result natively in a web browser.